# how to get node value from xml string in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml string and I want to get the value from ReturnCode in Python. How can I easily do this?

I've tried using element tree:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(response))
root = tree.getroot()
```

```xml
<API>
    <Result>
        <ErrorCode ErrorType=\"Success\">0</ErrorCode>
        <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
    </Result>
<API>
```

The actual response value looks like this-

```xml
'<API><Result><ErrorCode ErrorType=\"Success\">0</ErrorCode<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode></Result><API>'
```

I would like to be able to use the value from ReturnCode for additional logic.

Comment: _I've tried using element tree_ Show us what you tried.

Comment: @John Gordon added what I have tried

Comment: Also state the exact error you get **and** show the code that produces `response`, because it's unclear what this variable actually contains.

Comment: @Tomalak Great point, I guess that would help. I updated original post with that info! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As official documents [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Parse your xml document like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# root = ET.fromstring(your_xml_content)
# root.tag
body = '<API><Result><ErrorCode ErrorType="Success">0</ErrorCode><ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode></Result></API>'
response = ET.fromstring(body)
result = response.findall('Result')[0]
return_code = result.find('ReturnCode').text

## output '0'
```

Updated: I missed `result`.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the suggestion, however, I receive an error: ValueError: can only parse strings. It appears I am getting back a string. The exact response is: ```xmlResponse Body: "<API><Result><ErrorCode ErrorType=\"Success\">0</ErrorCode><ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode></Result></API>"```

Comment: updated last comment with what I think appears to be a string

Comment: `a = '<API><Result><ErrorCode ErrorType="Success">0</ErrorCode><ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode></Result></API>'` then, `ET.formstring(a)`

Comment: to clarify this is Python 3+. not sure if that matters here.  I am getting an unresolved error for "find" where you edited the original answer. This is the line with issue ```return_code = find('ReturnCode').text```

Comment: `return_code = result.find('ReturnCode').text.` the missed `result`, :P